Need guidance with Excel Add-in Edits - Changes not saved
I am working on a custom excel add-in abc.xlam. I have created several forms and modules in addition to the existing ones in the add-in. I am unable to edit any changes by clicking save.
A pop-up appears - You have modified a signed project. And it then asks me to save changes and discard certificate or to cancel save. On proceeding with discarding certificate, saving the file and opening it again .The add-in with the saved changes does not open.
Is there a way around this?
I have tried using the properties window to select add-in to false and saving changes in a xlsm file, and then loading the same. It too, does not work.

Are you changing the add-in on your PERSONAL.XLSB or just the application as you would open it normally?

"I have created several forms and modules in addition to the existing ones" did you create the existing ones or do they come from an external source? Have you tried generating an XLAM with only your forms and modules?

@MarkS. I am opening a normal xlsx workbook. Opening the add-in while on the workbook. And then importing forms and modules into the abc.xlam.

@cybernetic.nomad i did not create the existing modules. I have created additional modules/forms to be added to the existing ones. No, i haven't tried generating xlam with my own forms and modules

So if you're modifying the add-in are you exporting the add-in after modifying it, and re-importing that modified version of it when you use it? Usually with an add-in it's something that's in every workbook you open because it's installed to your machine or personal.xlsb; so if you're just editing it and saving your workbook that instance of the add-in in that specific workbook is the only one with the edits being saved.

@MarkS. Yeah that is exactly how it functions. Is it possible to edit the add-in, save the changes, close the workbook. And then reload the modified add-in with a new workbook?

Yes, but you need to do it in your PERSONAL.XLSB https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-save-all-your-macros-in-a-single-workbook-66c97ab3-11c2-44db-b021-ae005a9bc790
